# How to concatenate results on algolia

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

I would like to be able to concatenate data. 
Here is an example :

[
  {
    "type": "pen",
    "color": "blue",
  },
  {
    "type": "glass",
    "color": "red",
  },
  {
    "type": "pen",
    "color": "green",
  },
  {
    "type": "glass",
    "color": "violet",
  },
  {
    "type": "pen",
    "color": "yellow",
  },
  {
    "type": "glass",
    "color": "orange",
  }
]

Then, if I search for pen, I will get 3 results, one result for each colors. 
I would like only one result.

I tried to use a distinct but the algolia distinct is more like a filter, and not a concat. If I do a distinct on the attribute pen, i will get one result that might look like :

{
    "type": "pen",
    "color": "blue",
  },

What I would like to obtain is :

{
    "type": "pen",
    "color_list": ["blue", "green", "yellow"]
  },

I cannot find anything like that in the algolia/instant-search doc, so I wonder how to do it. Is there a real tool that can do this, or at least a hacky solution that could do the trick ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia won't concatenate for you, however what's usually done is to have your records hold two information:

- What colour this specific record represents
- what other colours exist for this product type

Which results in:

```
[{
  "type": "pen",
  "color": "red",
  "color_list": ["red", "blue", "green"]
},
{
  "type": "pen",
  "color": "green",
  "color_list": ["red", "blue", "green"]
},
...]
```

Set up `color` as a searchable attribute and use `distinct` to de-duplicate results; you can then have quite relevant results for searches such as "green pen", which would return the pen record with `"color": "green"` (thus you'd have a product picture with the right color for instance) but allow you to display color swatches of all the other available colours.

I hope this helps!
Please comment if you want to detail your use case more specifically :)